# Select / Copy Text Using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I heard that you can't copy text (in the browser) without using something like Flash; so, is there a way to select text by using an anchor and JavaScript or jQuery.

```
<p>Text to be copied</p>

<a>Copy Text Above</a>
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you asking how to copy selected text to the clipboard using javascript?

Comment: No. I'd like it so once the anchor has been clicked, the text (e.g. the text in the <p>) is copied to clipboard.

Comment: perhaps something with .text()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the following example html:

```
<div class="announcementInfoText">
    <p class="copyToClipboard">
        <a id="selectAll">Select All Text</a>
    </p>
    <textarea ID="description" class="announcementTextArea">This is some sample text that I want to be select to copy to the clipboard</textarea>
</div>
```

you can select the text within the textarea with the following jQuery:

```
$("#selectAll").click(function () {
    $(this).parents(".announcementInfoText").children("textarea").select();
});
```

Now that the text "*This is some sample text that I want to be select to copy to the clipboard*" is selected, you can simply hit Ctrl+C and the text is copied to the clipboard.

Answer (score 31):

On newer browsers, you can do this to select and copy.  This is a pure Javascript solution.

```
function copy_text(element) {
    //Before we copy, we are going to select the text.
    var text = document.getElementById(element);
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(text);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    //add to clipboard.
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

[This copy command works on all major browsers, Chrome, Firefox (Gecko), Internet Explorer, and Opera,  excluding Safari.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Browser_compatibility)

**Edit**: Note for the future - 
While the preceding still works, there is talk about moving to the [Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions) and using the [Clipboard interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText), which would look like `navigator.clipboard.writeText('text')`.  This standard is not yet finalized nor supported by many browsers.  As security becomes more of a concern, expect something like this in the future.

Answer (score 8):

I found this jQuery solution:

```js
$(function() {
 $('input').click(function() {
 $(this).focus();
 $(this).select();
 document.execCommand('copy');
 $(this).after("Copied to clipboard");
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="copy me!" />
```

[Source](https://www.coderomeos.org/select-and-copy-data-to-clipboard-using-jquery)

Comment: Finally, thank you. Much harder to find a simple quick jquery hack to do this than you would think. I only need it for local testing so it doesn't need to be the most robust code ever written.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution without running a flash-based plugin would be something like:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    window.prompt('Press ctrl/cmd+c to copy text', $(this).prev('p').text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JFFvG/